# Laravel with opcache

Tags: php, laravel, iis, opcache

I have problem with opcache. I'm running laravel 5.6 on IIS server with php 7.2 and when I enable opcache the app is crash.

> Fatal error: composerRequire1a7493bfe79afb8c03f982a7ea4d4348(): could not obtain parameters for parsing in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Fatal error: composerRequire1a7493bfe79afb8c03f982a7ea4d4348(): could not obtain parameters for parsing in Unknown on line 0

This issue is only on laravel (yii2 app with opcache on the same server is ok).
I tried:

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you use xammp go to Config > Select Apache (httpd.conf).

```
ServerName localhost:8080
```

Change everything 80 to 8080, it will become like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: No, I not using xammp or Apache. App is on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in PHP 7.2 Opcache system: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77092 please read carefully.

You can fix it:

1) via patch

2) downgrade to 7.1

3) wait until new releases